# How to clear history from a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am writing an script to dump my history log into another file "myhistory.log", and then clear that history. I have written the following set of commands:

```
date >> myhistory.log

history >> myhistory.log

history -c
```

Everything goes well except that the previous history is not cleared. I have tried the following variations:

```
\history -c
```

and

```
CLRH="history -c"
exec $CLRH
```

What I am missing probably??

Comment: It may seem a duplicate but my motive to ask the question was to learn how to specify the option while writing scripts. The history was just the example, as I stated in the title.

Comment: You complained the fact that history is not cleared. And I think that you are falling into [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If so, you can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/439785/edit) your question and make it clear.

Comment: I read your original post and still don't understand what you are asking. What options are you talking about? Do you want to know why the `history` builtin acts differently in scripts? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: The problem was that the last statement in the script "history -c" was clearing the history temporarily so I used "> ~/.bash_history" after "history -w" command. Now it is correct. Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 3):

By default, for bash, the command history are stored in `~/.bash_history` file.

As an alternative you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> ~/myhistory.log
cat ~/.bash_history >> ~/myhistory.log
echo -n "" > ~/.bash_history
```

This will append to `~/myhistory.log` (if the file is already there, else create a new file and write to it) the date when the script was run, dump your history, and clear the `~/.bash_history` file.